# Solving a convex optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, signal-processing

I need help to solve the following convex optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
X = argmin_{\mathbf{X}} \{ ||\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{L}||_F^2 \,\,\,+\,\, \lambda \,||\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{F}||_1 \} ~~~~~\color{red}{(1)}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{X} \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, $\mathbf{L} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, and $\mathbf{F} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, and $||.||_F$ represents the Frobenius norm, and $||.||_1$ is the $L_1$-norm.

$\bf{Before~you~give~your~opinions}:~$ In fact, one can directly expect to first recast equation (1) into independent $(n,p)$ parts. That is:
\begin{equation}
X_{i,j} = argmin_{X_{i,j}} \{ (X_{i,j} - L_{i,j})^2 + \lambda |X_{i,j} - F_{i,j}|\} ~~~\color{red} {(2)}
\end{equation}
where $i = 1, \cdots, n$ and $j = 1, \cdots, p$.

In this case, after derivating (2) w.r.t $X_{i,j}$, we get:

$2 (X_{i,j} - L_{i,j})~\pm~\lambda = 0$. Hence we will obtain a soft thersholding solution for $X_{i,j}$.

Is this the correct way to solve problem (1)?

Comment: You are right, if there is no constraint on $\mathbf{X}$ that links its component entries, then the objective function (1) can be minimized by minimizing (2) componentwise.  I think the minimization might be a little more complicated than your "derivating" of (2), since a critical point can also be a place where a derivative is undefined (not just zero).

Comment: If the $ {L}_{1} $ norm above is like both matrices are vectors then you can solve this as both matrices are vectors.